# Setting Back Button to a custom UIImage

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Currently I'm using my own custom images in UIBarButtonItems with the following code:

```
UIButton *profileBarButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 35.0f, 35.0f)];
    [profileBarButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile-barbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [profileBarButton addTarget:self.navigationController action:@selector(toggleMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:profileBarButton];
```

This works perfectly when I have a defined action to call, such as presenting a modalviewcontroller and turning on edit mode. However, I'm confused as to how I'd set the action for going back from one view to another, not modally? Is there a specific method I could call programmatically? Usually the navigationcontroller takes care of this...

Comment: I can't got wt is your real problem exactly :(

Comment: You are saying about bar button and you are creating a UIButton ??

Comment: yes. in order to set the background image of a UIBarButtonItem so that it doesn't have the standard iOS template button, you need to subclass a custom UIView unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for going back from one view to another, not modally you may write like this:

```
- (void) toggleMenu
{
    if (self.navigationController.visibleViewController == self)
    {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: while your at it, could you tell me how I might go about programmatically adding some padding between my leftbarbutton and the side of my view?

Comment: @Auser What do you mean?

Comment: huh actually it didn't, which is surprising. If I define a method called -(void)simpleback { [self dismissViewControllerAnimated...} it doesn't resign the view, even though the method is called (I NSlogged it). Any other thoughts? And what I mean is setting the width at which the BarButtonItem is placed?

Answer (score 0):

Check with this code...

```
    MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyNib" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];

[self presentModalViewController:nc animated:YES];

[vc release];
[nc release];
```

Then normally push code like...

```
    OtherViewController *vc = [[OtherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyOtherNib" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
[vc release];
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backButton.png"];
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[backButton setImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
backButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, backButtonImage.size.width, backButtonImage.size.height);
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(back) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *customBackBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBackBarItem;
```

In the @selector(back), "back" is the method that triggers the popup method of navigationcontroller. Like this:

```
-(void)back {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```